# C++ - Calling unused function from debugger

Tags: c++, llvm, lldb

Working on OSX with llvm and lldb, I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class A{
public:
    void f() __attribute__((noinline))
    {
        printf("f()\n");
    }

    void g() __attribute__((noinline))
    {
        printf("g()\n");
    }

};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.g();
    return 0;
}
```

When breaking in main(), and trying to call `p a.f()` from the debugger I get:

> error: Couldn't lookup symbols:   __ZN1A1fEv

calling `p g.f()`, however, works well.

I understand that f() may be optimized away, but is there any way to disable this optimization, so I can use it in the debugger anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding the symbol somewhere, e.g., `f;` (not `f();`) in `main()`.

Comment: Check your compiler command line optimization switch or IDE compiler settings. Practically all existing compilers allows to disable optimization.

Comment: As a quick hack, you can try to make the method `virtual`.

Comment: @lorro - can you explain the syntax?

Comment: @pts - It does work, but it increases `sizeof(A)`, which I'd like to avoid

Comment: @MarkS Sure it increases the size, because previously the whole method was not existent.

Comment: @maxik non-virtual member functions don't affect the size of an object

Comment: @MarkS - It merely takes the function pointer. You might also write `&f;` if you prefer, for clarity. It doesn't call anything and gets optimized away, but chances are, it forces the compiler & linker to include the function body because you take the address of it.

Comment: Please note that `f` gets optimized away by gcc 4.8.4 on Linux as well, even without optimization flags: `$ gcc t.cc; nm a.out | grep _ZN1A` only returns `g`, not `f`. Also with `$ gcc -g t.cc`.

Answer (score 2):

While moving the definition out of line may help in some cases, it won't help in all cases, e.g. if it's not an odr c++ member function but rather just a static function or if your entire program is LTO optimized and the function isn't referenced outside of the local translation unit.

In those cases (and probably this one as well) you should instead mark the function as `__attribute__((used))` to tell the compiler that the function is used and to make sure and generate code for it in the resulting object file - which also means that debug information will be generated as well.

Your final code for this will end up looking like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
  void f() __attribute__((noinline, used))
  {
    printf("f()\n");
  }

  void g() __attribute__((noinline))
  {
    printf("g()\n");
  }

};

int main()
{
  A a;
  a.g();
  return 0;
}
```

This is one of the reasons why `__attribute__((used))` was designed. From the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes):

> This attribute, attached to a function, means that code must be emitted for the function even if it appears that the function is not referenced. This is useful, for example, when the function is referenced only in inline assembly.
>   When applied to a member function of a C++ class template, the attribute also means that the function is instantiated if the class itself is instantiated.

This means that the function will be guaranteed to be emitted in all cases even if it isn't used.

(As a further addendum I haven't verified that this will actually work for LTO optimization - it probably should, but I'm betting it's a corner case that isn't often thought of, I didn't until just now and I work on LTO :)

Comment: Great, I've extended my answer with this option.

Comment: I'd really avoid using out of line definitions to attempt to solve this sort of problem. It will have additional wider ranging effects on the program and can still be broken by LTO or any other cross module type of optimization.

This use case is one of the reasons why __attribute__((used)) was created. I'll update my answer a bit more to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Move the definition of `f` outside the class:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class A {
public:
    void f();
    void g() __attribute__((noinline))
    {
        printf("g()\n");
    }
};
void A::f()
{
    printf("f()\n");
}
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.g();
    return 0;
}
```

This has worked for me with `$ g++ t.cc` and `$ g++ -g t.cc` on Linux with gcc 4.8.4. It may work with your toolchain as well.

```
$ g++ t.cc
$ nm a.out | grep _ZN1A
000000000040052e T _ZN1A1fEv
0000000000400562 W _ZN1A1gEv
```

As an alternative, as described in echristo's answer, add `used` to the attributes of `f`, and keep it inside the class. That also works with $ g++ t.cc`and`$ g++ -g t.cc`:

```
$ g++ -g t.cc
0000000000400548 W _ZN1A1fEv
0000000000400560 W _ZN1A1gEv
```

Adding `used` also works with `g++ -O2 -g t.cc`.